# Adding forks after stream has been started?

Tags: node.js, highland.js

I have a node.js application using Highland stream. It consumes a data source and it needs to send data into multiple destinations. The trouble is, the destinations are discovered dynamically by reading the data and creating destination streams based on the data.

This means I cannot `.fork` the stream to add destinations (because a stream that has started consuming cannot be forked, right?)

Is there anything else I can do?

My current approach is to have a `.consume` where I create destination streams and write data into the destinations. The result is ugly and messy.